# How to remove the trailing white spaces in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function that accepts an input string consisting of alphabetic
>   characters and removes all the trailing whitespace of the string and
>   returns it without using any .strip() method. For example if:
>
> input_string = "  Hello       "
>
> then your function should return an output string such as:
>        output_string = "  Hello"

This is my code:

```
def Trailing_White_Space (input_str):

    count = 0
    for i in range (len(input_str) + 1, 0):
        if (input_str[i] != ' '):
            count = i
            break
    new_s = input_str[len(input_str):count]
    return (new_s)

#Main Program
input_str = "    Hello    "
result = Trailing_White_Space (input_str)
print (result)
```

I am certain that the logic is correct. I have dry run the code with possible test cases. Still my code doesn't give any output. Please help.

Comment: BTW, you should accept one of the answers on your previous (related) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551794/how-to-remove-or-strip-off-white-spaces-without-using-strip-function).

Comment: Your assignment is to remove **all** the trailing whitespace, not just the `' '` space chars. You also need to remove the other whitespace chars like `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'`, etc. The clean way to handle that is to use the `.isspace` method, like I suggested on your other question.

Comment: Did you try using `re.sub( )`?

Comment: Dude I don't know what it is. I am just a beginner here.

Comment: @KaranThakkar Posted an answer with the same. Using `re` the function is of two lines :)

Comment: @Prashanth: I don't think Karan's teacher would appreciate a regex-based answer to this assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct the line where you assign `new_s` variable.

```
new_s = input_str[:count+1]
```

Also, since you're loop needs to be decremented after every iteration. Replace `0` with `-1`.

```
for i in range(len(input_str)-1, -1, -1):
```

**EDIT:** Refer [@InbarRose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35554537/2932244) for a much better alternative.

Comment: this gives me output as '   Hell'

Comment: I want the output as '  Hello'

Comment: @KaranThakkar - Make it `new_s = input_str[:count+1]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the main reason you're having trouble:

```
input_str[len(input_str):count]
```

If the slice *starts* at `len(input_str)` then you wont get any characters out of it at all. You need to only use `[:count]`, except that you're also not getting `count` correctly.

In order to loop from the end you have to use the third argument for range to decrement your value, so it has to be

```
for i in range(len(input_str) - 1, -1, -1):
```

You want -1, which reduces the value by one each time. You also want to start at `len-1` otherwise you get invalid indices, and if you want to end at 0 you need to pass -1, since range doesn't go to the end value.

Now you can get use the `count` and slice `input_str` properly:

```
return input_str[:count]
```

Comment: Awesome analysis. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why are we using len-1? When I run the program I get the output as "   Hell" which is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to see a one-liner answer. This is it:

```
from string import whitespace as ws
def remove_trailing_whitespace(t):
    return t[:-next(i for i, c in enumerate(t[::-1]) if c not in ws)]
```

Example:

```
>>> print '"{}"'.format(remove_trailing_whitespace('  hello  '))  # spaces
"  hello"
>>> print '"{}"'.format(remove_trailing_whitespace('  hello\n'))  # newline
"  hello"
>>> print '"{}"'.format(remove_trailing_whitespace('  hello\t'))  # tab
"  hello"
>>> print '"{}"'.format(remove_trailing_whitespace('  hello \t\n '))  # space, newline, tab
"  hello"
```

Bonus: all whitespace chars, not just space, and best efficiency.

Comment: This is the best answer. Solves OP's issue efficiently. Added a link to your answer in mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try using `re.sub()`

```
import re

def remove(my_string):
    new_string = re.sub(r'(.*?\w)([ \t\n\r]*)', r'\1', my_string)
    return(new_string)

my_string = str(input())
modified = remove(my_string)
print(modified)
```

**Explanation:**

`re` is a module in python for regular expressions.

`re.sub(pattern, replacing_pattern, string_to_be_modified)` is the syntax.

Here, any character in the square braces (`\w` -> any character, -> space, `\t` -> tab, `\n` -> newline, `\r` -> carriage return) when encountered is replaced by `''`(Nothing). Hence you get a stripped string.

Find all the regex matches [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: The `\s` is for general whitespace matching, not just the space char. See the [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for details; also note that the behaviour is slightly different in Python 3 vs Python 2, due to Unicode issues.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for pointing it out. I've modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`range()` by default goes up.  If you want it to go in reverse, you have to set the step explicitly.  Also, you don't want to start at `len(input_str)` *+* 1.  You want to start at `len(input_str)` *-* 1.  For any iterable, x, `x[len(x)]` is not defined.  `x[len(x) + 1]` is even farther off.  To get the last element, you should use `len(input_str) - 1`.  Also, if you set the second number to `0`, then the first element will not be evaluated.  The second argument to `range()` is *exclusive*, so you should go one number farther than you think you should:

```
def Trailing...
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(input_str) - 1, -1, -1):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` loop:

```
my_str = ' hello   '
while len(my_str) > 0 and my_str[-1] == ' ':
    my_str = my_str[:-1]

print(my_str) # prints: ' hello'
```

Comment: This does not strip `'\t'`, `'\r'`, etc.

Answer (score -6):

Your loop is not going through. You have to specify that it is decrementing. Below is the working code.

```
def Trailing_White_Space (input_str):

    count = 0
    for i in range (len(input_str)-1, 0, -1):
        if (input_str[i] != ' '):
            count = i
            break
    slice_index= (len(input_str)-count)-1
    new_s = input_str[0:-1*slice_index]
    return (new_s)

#Main Program
input_str = "    Hello    "
result = Trailing_White_Space (input_str)
print (result)
```

Comment: OP says "without using .strip()"