# Is there a way to make this code cleaner? I'm still learning Python. Thank you in advance. Without using Strip method

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, while-loop, slice

This code will remove leading and trailing whitespace, newline, and tab.

```
def clean(message):
    while message[0] in '\n':
        message = message[1:]
    while message[0] in '\t':
        message = message[1:]
    while message[0] in ' ':
        message = message[1:]
    while message[-1] in '\t':
        message = message[:-1]
    while message[-1] in ' ':
        message = message[:-1]
    while message[-1] in '\n':
        message = message[:-1]
    while message[-1] in ' ':
        message = message[:-1]
    return message
```

Comment: One possible approach might involve [using regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and finding/replacing the unwanted characters/items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove or strip off white spaces without using strip() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551794/how-to-remove-or-strip-off-white-spaces-without-using-strip-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strip`. By default `strip` removes all white-space characters e.g. `'\n'`, `'\t'`, `' '`, from both beginning and end.

```
def clean(message):
    return message.strip()
```

Or you can use `message.strip('\n\t ')` if you want to be more explicit. You can add other characters to remove additional characters from both ends.

Since this is builtin method, it will be a lot faster than the while loops.

---

Not using `strip` at OP's request:
Simply combining some while loops

```
def clean(message):
    while message[0] in '\n\t ':
        message = message[1:]
    while message[-1] in '\n\t ':
        message = message[:-1]
    return message
```

It's also better to use index, so you don't have to modify `message` in every loop. Faster this way too.

```
def clean(message):
    start, end = 0, -1
    while message[start] in '\n\t ':
        start += 1
    while message[end] in '\n\t ':
        end -= 1
    return message[start:end]
```

Comment: Ah, yes! I forgot to mention without using the strip method.

Comment: Much obliged! This looks way better than what I had.